# Angular 17 standalone components slow down project

Tags: angular, angular17, angular-standalone-components

I have a huge project on Angular 17, I tried to migrate all of my components to standalone but there is an issue.
For example for my HomeComponent on module based Angular 3 js chunks are being downloaded with total size of 5.3MB and after migration 80 chunks are being download with total size of 3.9MB. Total size is significantly reduced but on the other hand number of chunks that are being downloaded is increased which is causing my application to run slower.
( these 80 chunks are created because my home page is using multiple components and modals and pipes and directives and .. which are all divided into different chunks after changing them to standalone )

Comment: Make sure your HTTP server uses HTTP/2, the number increase should not be an issue.

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler The number increase is an issue because their downloads are not started together for example it downloads index.html which includes main.js and after downloading main.js it understands I need sidebar chunk so it downloads x.js after that because sidebar component is using another component y.js starts to download and so on ..

Comment: Apparently, this is by design: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/26307